# Scale feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, scale

I am trying to scale (up and down) feature(s), similar to ArcGIS where the first click specifies the scale reference point and the second click specifies the scale factor, but couldn't find a solution that works for Version 3..1 of QGIS, The Affinity command is not available and the vector transform plugin seems outdated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [QAD Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) which has a scale option, and you can enter a scale factor to scale your feature. If you are familiar with AutoCAD, this plugin works almost same, and it is very powerful.

For the QAD plugin to work properly, the features should be projected either in meter or foot. It does not work with geographic coordinates. Also, you should work in editing mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. Unfortunately, all the data I have is from a shapefile import that has WGS  geographical projection, so I couldn't make use of the plugin.